# Full ajax/pjax site

Tags: pjax

I´m planning to make a full dynamic site using pjax, with static menu (only the content will be updated with pjax). How bad is this?
The site that i have planned to implat this on have a lots of data on it,  most images.

I have tested my solution on my local machine and it seems to work but in production it will probably be slow or what do you guys think? Are this bad practise?

Now on pjax start i slide out my container to the left, and slide in the new content from the right. I have noticed a small performance lost when i do this in Safari and FireFox. Should i skip my solution and just do regular updates of the page? I want to do something like Twitters iPhone app, but on the web.

The reason i want to do this are that i have a full size google maps with a lot of pins that take some time to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found Tubrolinks (http://www.github.com/rails/turbolinks) that would be included in Rails 4.0, its great adn i think a good answer to my question.